# Handle packet loss using netcat, shell script in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send the file contents using nc command in unix line by line to a port where the server is listening for further processing.

I am using the following code:

Client:

```
for inFile in `ls /home/dbadmin/input_data/*.dat`
do
        while read line
        do
                echo $line
                echo $line |nc -C 127.0.0.1 7870
        done<$inFile
done
```

Server:

```
echo "socket program"
while true
do
   echo `nc -l 7870`
done
```

> I have 75 lines in the file at the sending end, but I am getting only
>   60 lines in the receiver end. Can you guys help me handling this!

**Updated Code to check for the numbers instead of file reading**

```
#!/bin/bash
c=1
while [ $c -le 10 ]
do
        echo "Welcone $c times"
        echo $c |nc -C 127.0.0.1 7870
        (( c++ ))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are losing packets.

When you do a "read" and "echo" in the shell, it drops whitespace and subtly changes your files, so I would suggest doing it "1 file at a time" rather than "1 line at a time" and avoiding "read" and "echo". Like this:

Server:

```
echo "socket program"
while true
do
   nc -l 7870
done
```

Client:

```
#!/bin/bash
for inFile in *.dat
do
   nc -C 127.0.0.1 7870 < $inFile
done
```

**EDITED**
If you want to test whether packets are getting dropped, try sending a large volume of data and seeing if the same amount arrives as is sent:

Client:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Send 1GB of zeroes
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1m count=1000 |nc -C 127.0.0.1 7870
```

Sample output:

```
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes transferred in 6.618385 secs (158433821 bytes/sec)
```

Server:

```
echo "socket program"
while true
do
   # Receive stuff and say how much
   nc -l 7870 | wc -c
done
```

Sample output:

```
 1048576000
```

I was wondering if the problem might be that netcat doesn't set SO_REUSEADDR to allow addresses to be re-used. You could leave the client as is and try this as a Perl implementation of the server and see if that helps...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::Socket;
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET ( 
   LocalPort => '7870', 
   Proto => 'tcp', 
   Listen => 1, 
   Reuse => 1, 
);

die "Could not create socket: $!\n" unless $sock;

while(my $new_sock = $sock->accept()){
   while(<$new_sock>) { print $_; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the suggestion.
I am in need of sending line by line, So I have added the above code, which is sending 10 numbers and I am getting only 8 numbers. remaining 2 numbers were lost.

Comment: And what happens when you change it?

Comment: Hi Mark, I can see the same output that you have mentioned above.
Here is the sample file that I need to send by line by line. similar way I have n number files.  
http://dpaste.com/hold/1586897/

Note: I do not want to send the whole file, Actuall I need to send line by line. Why because already I have another script, which is doing some processing behind and it will write to the file. I just want to link that output of the script to send the each value in the stream

Comment: Mark, It means there is no packet loss? So what will be issue? Can you please describe to understand the issue here!

Comment: If you can send GB through your network, there is nothing wrong with it. Try adding "-t" switch to client and server so you use TCP instead of UDP.

Comment: I tried to add t (echo $c |nc -tC 127.0.0.1 7870) and executed that while loop which is send the 10 numbers. But still 2 numbers are lost.

Comment: I can only imagine that the problem is opening and closing the port so quickly, and maybe some messages get lost in between. You could try adding a "sleep 1" between sending lines to see if it works reliably like that.

Comment: Mark, for some of the executions I can get the 10 numbers and for some of them, I got only 7 or 8 numbers in the receiver.

Comment: Mark, already I have included the sleep and tried, it works fine. But we should not put a delay, because it is time critical process, it should reach immediately in the receiver end

Comment: I have no other ideas, except maybe to start listening on, say, 8 ports on the server and then let the client send first message in first port, second message on second port and so on then re-using first port for 9th message. Sorry, no other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an [x]inetd-based service and see if that helps:

Edit /etc/inetd.conf

Add a line like this:

```
7870 stream tcp nowait root /usr/sbin/tcpd /home/youruser/bin/receiver
```

Re-init inetd, something like this

```
sudo pkill -HUP inetd
```

Write a shell script called /home/youruser/bin/receiver that reads the messages from its stdin and does whatever you want along these lines

```
#!/bin/bash
cat - >> /tmp/log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

(I cannot say your usage of `nc -l` is very good; perhaps it is acceptable only as a quick&dirty hack.)

Your problem is technically different from packet loss.

```
while true
do
   echo `nc -l 7870`
done
```

When you this loop, there will be a short period of time when `nc` is not listening for 7870/TCP.  Then the sender `nc` will fail to establish a connection and return with an error, leading to the loss of information.

This is how to retry sending the same data until `nc` successfully returns.

```
while read line; do
    echo $line
    while ! echo $line | nc -q0 localhost 33445; do : ; done
done < /etc/fstab
```

(Note that the command line options accepted by my `nc` seem to be different from yours.)